# How to get values from a 2-d Array with indices

Tags: python, numpy

For example I have following 2-D array.

```
>>>np.array(((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))) 
>>>array([[1, 2],
          [3, 4],
          [5, 6]])
```

I want to get a element from each column. For example, I want to get `3` from 1st column, `6` from 2rd column.
How can do it with a indices[1,2]. `1` means 2rd element from 1st column, `2` means 3rd element from 2rd column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with so-called [fancy indexing](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2):

```
In [57]: x = np.array(((1,2),(3,4),(5,6)))

# np.arange(x.shape[1]) gives [0,1], the column indices
# needed to select "one from each column"
In [58]: x[[1,2], np.arange(x.shape[1])]
Out[58]: array([3, 6])
```

---

Or you could use [np.choose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
In [44]: np.choose([1,2], x)
Out[44]: array([3, 6])
```